# Read Excel file and write in other excel at specific sheet using POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am reading an Excel file and writing the content into an already existing file based on sheet name. The Excel file has 3 header columns.

```
XSSFSheet conSheet = workbook.getSheet("EMPLOYYEE");
XSSFRow headerRow = conSheet.getRow(0);
XSSFRow dataRow = conSheet.createRow(conSheet.getLastRowNum() + 1);
int physicalNumberOfCells = headerRow.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
for (int i = 0; i < physicalNumberOfCells; i++) {
    XSSFCell headerCell = headerRow.getCell(i);
    if (headerCell != null) {
        String stringCellValue = headerCell.getStringCellValue();
        ConvertsColumn charcol = ConvertsColumn.getEnum(stringCellValue);
        XSSFCell dataCell = dataRow.createCell(i);
        if (charcol != null) {
            try {
                FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("file..anme");
                Workbook wb1 = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
                Sheet sheet1 = wb1.getSheetAt(0);
                Iterator < Row > iterator = sheet1.iterator();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    Row nextRow = iterator.next();
                    Iterator < Cell > cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();
                    while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                        Cell nextCell = cellIterator.next();
                        int columnIndex = nextCell.getColumnIndex();
                        System.out.println(columnIndex + "" + nextCell);
                        switch (columnIndex) {
                            case 0:
                                dataCell.setCellValue(nextCell.getStringCellValue());
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                dataCell.setCellValue(nextCell.getStringCellValue());
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                dataCell.setCellValue(nextCell.getStringCellValue());
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We are Using POI. When data is writing to the Excel file it is over-writen with the first column and only one column data is adding with one value...

Comment: Why are you creating a row every time? What happens if you follow the documentation, only create each row once, and get+use it on other occassions?

Comment: can umake it clear please